# Is this question about why a law isn't enforced on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I was reading this question: [How is it possible for millions to use pirated software at home and never get arrested?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/2163/how-is-it-possible-for-millions-to-use-pirated-software-at-home-and-never-get-ar)

This does not seem like a legal question, and my first throught is to mark it as off-topic, but it seems others disagree (many upvotes, no close votes [that I can see]), so I thought it best to discuss it here.

Answer (score 9):

**Yes**, that and similar questions should be, and are, on-topic. It is both covered by the "Legal process and procedure" and the "Dealing with legal professionals" provisions in the Help Center's "What topics can I ask about here?" article.

Comment: That particular question is interesting, because it attracts non-legal answers, which I would normally expect to get voted down. This probably wasn't helped by the fact that it was a [Hot Network Question](http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) for three days, which is longer than I can remember any other question staying there (most age away after a day). However, the question itself, as you say, is on-topic.